# Maven and pom.xml

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, maven, m2eclipse, tapestry

I'm using m2eclipse and trying to learn some tapestry.  I'm trying to update my project to pull some different resources from maven.  (Or at least, I think that's what I'm trying to do).

Here's part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

The artifact id used to be tapestry-core, but the tutorial I'm using said to change it to tapestry-hibernate so I can use hibernate.  I changed the pom.xml and saved it, but I'm not sure what command exactly I'm supposed to execute exactly.  I tried using some of the plugin commands like "update dependencies", but I still don't have a hibernate.cfg.xml  file generated, which I think I should have, right?

Comment: I ended up just creating the hibernate.cfg.xml myself.  The tutorial didn't specify that it would appear automatically, nor did it say I had to create my own so maybe this is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I changed the pom.xml and saved it, but I'm not sure what command exactly I'm supposed to execute exactly.

m2eclipse should setup the new dependencies (and download it if necessary) after you changed the pom.xml without any required action.

> I tried using some of the plugin commands like "update dependencies", but I still don't have a hibernate.cfg.xml file generated, which I think I should have, right?

No, the `hibernate.cfg.xml` won't get automagically generated just because you changed a dependency (it is possible to generate an `hibernate.cfg.xml` with the [`hibernate3-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/) but I don't think you are using it and it's really not easy to use).

Comment: Thanks, I had gone ahead and created the file on my own

Answer (score 1):

You need both dependencies: tapestry-core and tapestry-hibernate. On the other hand, tapestry-hibernate depencds on tapestry-core, so the latter is included automatically by Maven. tapestry-hibernate doesn't create a hibernate.cfg.xml for you.